# selecting number of rows from resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Suppose a query "select * from employee" returns 80 rows. I need to display middle rows that is from 20th row to 50th row.

I know, like to display first 20 rows we have option like "select top 20 * from employee" but if we need middle rows how to get it in **MS SQL** specifically.

I m new to this SQL queries...Can anybody answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-ms-sql-server).  :-)