# SQL Select query that returns a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Row Offset in MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-ms-sql-server)

I want to select a range from x1 to x2. Just like you can select the top results:

```
SELECT TOP X * FROM TABLE

SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tUsers
```

But I would like to select middle results. So if I want results 10-20 is there a way to query that?

```
SELECT 10-20 * FROM TABLE?
```

Comment: What Database distro are you using? (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-ms-sql-server, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server

Comment: @Karl: SQL Server, because other databases don't support the `SELECT TOP` syntax

Comment: Sort of a duplicate. I looked before I posted and I think this one is phrased better.

Comment: @intgr - Haha, I missed that. I haven't dealt with anything other than SQL server for the mostpart, so I'm not well versed in the syntactic differences. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With SQL Server :

[Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-ms-sql-server)

With MySQL :

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 10, 20
```

With Oracle :

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE rownum >= 10 and rownum < 20;
```

With PostgreSQL :

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 20 OFFSET 10
```

`your_table` must be replaced by your real table name

Comment: The backticks are illegal in Oracle and PostgreSQL (actually in any database except MySQL) - and they are absolutely unnecessary even for the MySQL example

Comment: \`your_table\` must be replaced by the real table name...

Comment: But the backticks are still illegal (and non-standard)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name \`your_table\` must be replaced by the real table name !!!

Comment: And just one more thing, a comon error in Oracle 8 through 9i is to use RowNum like that (don't know if they've changed in more recent versions). Romnum is the last thing calculated by the DB, meaning that if you use Rownum > 1 it will always return no rows (since no row will ever fill the fist position, no other row will have rownum > 1.

Comment: And just to be instructive about the issue mentioned above, you would have to select the rowNums on an inner select (so they would be calculated and returned to the outter-most select as regular data) and then, on an outter select, use it like that (rownum >= 10). Again, I'm only sure about this on version 8, 8i and 9i.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server 2005 or above you can use a `CTE` and the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH TblCte as
(
SELECT  *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderCol) RowNumber
FROM    Table
)
SELECT  *
FROM    TblCte
WHERE   RowNumber between 10 and 20
```

In SQL Server 2000 or below, it was quite difficult and inefficient:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/transactsql/thread/e92d9b03-42ad-4ab9-9211-54215e7b9352

Answer (score 1):

In mysql this is

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10,20
```

Answer (score -2):

What DB are you using? If you're on Oracle, try

```
where rownum >= 10 and rownum < 20;
```

Comment: That won't work - the rownum must be evaluated with a derived table: select * from (select col_!, rownum as rn from your_table) where rn >= 10 and rn < 20;