# How to select nth row in SQL Server 2005 database query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005 query is as follows......

```
SELECT ClgId 
FROM IdMaker_DB  
WHERE Course = 'B-Tech' AND [Class] = 'Ist Year'
AND Branch = 'Computer Science and Engineering' 
ORDER BY ClgId
```

It works fine and selects all entries of `Computer Science and Engineering Ist Year`
but is select only first row, how can I select nth row......

Comment: This may be a duplicated question: You can find an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from (
 SELECT ClgId ,row_number() over (order by ClgId) as rn  FROM IdMaker_DB 
where Course ='B-Tech' and [Class]='Ist Year'

 and Branch='Computer Science and Engineering'   ) a where rn=n   --replace the n
```

Comment: row_number() is the key, but you will want to put it before the FROM.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.

Comment: @Dinesh Gehlot please try now.

Comment: @adam thats what happens when you re in phone + you wife talking to your ear.....:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 ClgId 
FROM IdMaker_DB  
where Course ='B-Tech' 
and [Class]='Ist Year'
and Branch='Computer Science and Engineering' 
and clgid not in 
    (SELECT top N - 1 ClgId 
    FROM IdMaker_DB  
    where Course ='B-Tech' 
    and [Class]='Ist Year'
    and Branch='Computer Science and Engineering' 
    ORDER BY ClgId)
ORDER BY ClgId
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM   student 
WHERE  id IN 
       ( 
        SELECT TOP n id 
        FROM student 
       ) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: This does not provide a correct answer to the question asked. Using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` produces results of an [undefined order](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx). Not sure why this was posted, seeing as how two valid answers were already given ... over a year ago.