# Select nth result from a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I was wondering if there is a way to select, for example, the third result from a query. I have looked into LIMIT and OFFSET but I'm not 100% sure if it applies to SQL Server, however I've been told that there is something to do what I want in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: i think u want to return only n'th  row by your query is its rigt

Comment: @RenjithKN Exactly, from my query (Which could be simple or complex), I want to select the nth row from the results of the query I just ran

Comment: possible duplicate of [Row Offset in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server)

Comment: @juergend This is specifically aimed at MSSQL 2012, that question was posted in 2011 and was aimed at any SQL version (No answers were aimed at 2012)

Comment: @juergend I would agree with the duplicate only if there were some way to emphasize the SQL Server 2012 answer. It's not the accepted answer but it is the best answer for SQL Server 2012 specifically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM     YourTable
ORDER BY OrderingColumn ASC 
OFFSET  2 ROWS /*Skip first 2 rows*/
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Note: You cannot use `OFFSET ... FETCH` without doing an `ORDER BY` first

Comment: Just got this to work myself, I knew it had something to do with offset but missed the fetch. Also, as a note, you cannot use OFFSET FETCH without doing an ORDER BY first

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend

```
select * from table ORDER BY OrderingColumn ASC LIMIT n,1
```

This is a quirk of limit where if you give it a range, it only returns that range. It works in MySQL too.

Answer (score -1):

Can’t you just select the second index? This is the way i would take say the third post in my table.

//index 3
$index3 = DB::query(‘SELECT * from posts’)[2];

Then you will have an array that is ready to go for you.