# Linq to SQL - Random Select Order and Paging

Tags: linq

We have a database with 2,00,000 vendor in 100 plus category, if someone visit the website we want to allow them to select a category and show them 25 Vendor per page, first we kept order by VendorId but it always use to get first 25, but we removed it, but now in paging it sometime repeat the vendor, is there a way to get random 25 vendor and also keep the paging.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can randomize your result but everytime you dot he query, it will create new random list so unless you randomize and save the randomized state in your Code and page over it, it cant be done straightforward way.
refer, [SQL Query results pagination with random Order by in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075066/sql-query-results-pagination-with-random-order-by-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this requirement is impossible to implement if a new random order is needed every time, there needs to be good performance and every item should have equal chance to get selected. I believe you should redesign the way your application works.

One possible workaround is to have a couple of columns in a table and fill them with random numbers. When a user requests the list assign the random column to him (stick it in the URL for example). Then do an order by that column and display the results. Randomly switch 4-5 columns to create the appearance of randomness. Update the random numbers in the columns once a day.