# Getting the n-th record in the SQL database where the table is result of another query

Tags: sql-server

I have number of users, each taking 10 questions and leave some time stamps. What I ideally want to do is to find the complete time of the n-th user where n is determined by the ascending order of time stamps, not the user ids.

This will not work, but to give you a feel of what I need I would be very happy if this could run:

```
SELECT <N-TH> MAX(u.time) AS maxTime FROM Users u
Group BY u.userId   ORDER BY maxTime
```

Any thoughts? right now I am running

```
SELECT MAX(u.time) AS maxTime FROM Users u
Group BY u.userId   ORDER BY maxTime
```

get the result as array and then find the n-th entry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Row Offset in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server)

Comment: Please indicate what version of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Many possible ways but just off cuff...could use CTEs or subquery.
Try

```
SELECT MAX([maxTime]) AS [LastEntry] FROM (
    SELECT MAX(u.time) AS maxTime,u.userId 
    FROM Users u 
    GROUP BY u.userId,u.time) t
```

OK, try this...

```
WITH CTE ([maxTime], [userId ]) AS (
    SELECT MAX([time]) AS [maxTime],
        [userId]
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY [userId])
    SELECT MAX([maxTime]) AS [maxTime]
    FROM CTE;
```

HTH

Dave

Comment: Unfortunately, the grouping commands cannot be used in a sub query

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ROW_NUMBER()` function

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY maxTime) as RowNum, MAX(u.time) AS maxTime FROM Users u
Group BY u.userId
) A
WHERE RowNum = NthNumber
ORDER BY maxTime
```

where `NthNumber` is the ranking number.

Comment: Unfortunately, order by cannot be used in sub-queries.

Comment: You're right @user1288502 actually I just forget to remove it. But it could now be sorted if it is used outside which my query already had.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` UserId, and apply `ROW_NUMBER` based on `max(u.time)` to create a ranking pseudo-column that you can then filter on

```
select min_utime, max_utime, userId from (
select min(u.time) min_utime, max(u.time) max_utime, u.userId,
row_number() over (order by max(u.time) asc) as ranker
from Users u
group by u.userId
) Z  where ranker  = @n
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the first 10 rows as sorted by the maximum time:

```
SELECT TOP 10 userId, MAX(time) AS maxtime
FROM Users
GROUP BY userId
ORDER BY maxtime ASC
```

Then just reverse the order and take the top row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
  SELECT TOP 10 userId, MAX(time) AS maxtime
  FROM Users
  GROUP BY userId
  ORDER BY maxtime ASC
) s
ORDER BY maxtime DESC;
```