# Invalid query syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like so: `SELECT TOP 20 a.Job_No FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF` Which gives me the first 20 results, but I want to start at 20 and get 20 results, how do I set an Offset?

I tried: OFFSET 20 at the end of the query and I got this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'
```

I know in mysql its Offset, is it something different in SQL?

This gives me an error:

```
SELECT 
    a.Job_No 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) as RowNum 
    FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF 
    FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
        ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
    INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
        ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
        ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No
        ) AS MyDerivedTable 
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 20

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

This is the closest I have come:

```
SELECT a.Job_No, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) as datacounter FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No
```

but in the where clause for datacounter it says it does not exists

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx)? Are you running SQL Server 2012 or better?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this covers fictitious syntax

Comment: Maybe try starting with something simpler. Right now you have `FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF` which would fail regardless of any of this paging syntax you're trying.

Comment: Something that you might consider is identifying a format for your SQL code that you can accept and then applying that consistently. You can observe from those that have edited your question, it's nearly impossible to parse, much less comprehend issues when it scrolls for several pages.

Comment: @AaronBertrand MySQL has option for LIMIT syntax with OFFSET. Either `LIMIT row_count` (0 offset) or `LIMIT offset, row_count` or `LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset`

Comment: @ypercube OK, still, guessing at syntax and refusing to read the documentation and throwing hands in the air when it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code you've posted your problem is simple. you have two "`FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF`"'s

See.

```
SELECT 
    MyDerivedTable.Job_No 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.Jon_No,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) as RowNum 
    FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF --<--What's up with this guy here?
    FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
        ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
    INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
        ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
        ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No
        ) AS MyDerivedTable 
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 20
```

Still Think the below solution is superior but this is why you're getting that syntax error.

Comment: Removing the extra from, gives me a new error 'a.Job_No' could not be bound. State 1, Line 1

Comment: @user3922763 jeezus, change your outer `SELECT` to `SELECT MyDerivedTable.Job_No` and please try to read the error messages to debug your code

Comment: @user3922763 Please go to [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) or something. You need to do some debugging yourself.

Comment: You removed the as a one I'm assuming.

Comment: @Zane the problem is with the outer `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

take a look here: [Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server) It looks as though there's no direct equivalent keyword, however the same effect can still be achieved via a little bit of a workaround.

```
SELECT Job_No
FROM (
SELECT Job_No, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
FROM MyTable
) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```

replace `@startRow` and `@endRow` with your starting and ending row numbers.

Update: Basing on updated info in the question:

```
 SELECT 
 Job_No 
 FROM (
 SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) as RowNum 
 FROM dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
 INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
 ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
 INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
 ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
 ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No
 ) AS MyDerivedTable 
 WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 20
```

That's my best guess anyways.  It looks like you had 2 from statements back to back....

Comment: I do not understand that syntax

Comment: SQL Server 2012 or better [has much better syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: True, I was going for a safer solution, as version used wasn't stated....@user3922763 answer updated some for clarification.

Comment: Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Depends on the version of SQL Server that's being used.  If you're on 2012 or newer, go with the link that @AaronBertrand provided, if not, then unfortunately no.

Comment: 2008...I have updated my question, with I have tried and what error I am getting

Comment: Please use the code button {} to format blocks of code. Backticks are for inline words here and there.

Comment: Fair enough.  Bad habits die hard.

Comment: Not big on indenting for readability, either, I take it. Anyway your code still has an error - the outer column looks for `a.Job_No` but the derived table is not called `a`. Usually setting up a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) prevents these errors caused by untested code.