# PHP PDO set limit and offset

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to build an application in PHP PDO. I need my queries to be very generic i.e. a same query should run in any DBMS, how can I achieve this ?

For example,

MySQL - `select * from emp limit 10,20`;

and

MS SQL - `select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() as cnt from emp)x where cnt between 10 and 20` (something like this)

How can I achieve both of these in in PDO using generic code. SO that i just have to change dbms (and drivers) and then rest of the things work fine.

Please help.

Thanks !

Comment: Write a class for every RDBMS with the same methods.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server as you know has a completely different approach to 'limiting', and in particular SQL Server has no notion of the 'range' ability that MySQL offers, to do this you need to wrap the query in a sub-select.

So... you're probably looking at some ORM/query builder so that you can notionally write queries and set limits/ranges and then this will need some method to generate a MySQL or SQL Server version of the query.

Here is an example of the query you want SQL Server style ;) [Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server)

A good approach is using something like Doctrine and it's Query Language - http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: Thanks Brian for the help. I read PDO is a abstraction layer, hence thought it will have provision for such kind of a query.

Comment: PDO is definatley the way to go with PHP and database interaction, but a range query in SQL Server is as you know a bit of a hack at best, so some other layer like doctrine or you're own ORM/query building tool will be needed on top and PDO will do the actuall execution of generated queries :)