# SQL - How to ignore a $nb result?

Tags: mysql, sql, web

I have to print some SQL's select's requests answers on a web page.
Because it's a to large result, i need to print it 500 per 500.
Like phpmyadmin, how can i say (with a SQL request) to get my results per 500 ?
Actualy i'm doing like this :

```
SELECT * FROM taches WHERE id<=1435 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
```

And updating the id limit at every click on the "next button".
Can i say to SQL something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM taches ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500 EXCEPTFIRSTRESULT 500
```

(I know this can't work, but is it possible with an other way ? Thanks.

Comment: `distinct *` is useless because the PK will be included which makes all rows unique (by definition) and therefor `distinct` will not remove any rows. Btw: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks, it's true the distinct is useless (It is a habit) But it don't solve my problem :/

Comment: It's a bad habit. And again: which DBMS are you using? Does it support OFFSET?

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin with wamp. Is that what ou need ? So "OFFSET 500" will ignore the 500 first result ? I think my answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh), the answer is :
"SELECT * FROM taches ORDER BY `taches`.`id` ASC LIMIT 500 , 500".
Have a good day :D