# server side pagination in mvc 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, pagination

Created mvc 4 application.currently In that Application I'm loading thousands of records using client side pagination.
this is how I do it

1. Using select all Linq query I'm selecting all the recodes in that
   table
2. Then using jquery tablesorter plugin its deviding all those
   records in to 10 by 10 chunks , showing those results page by page

here a picture of it

[image]

Since this is large set of data its taking too much time to load.There for I decided to do this using server side pagination.

but I have no idea to achieve this , could you suggest me a way to do this using jquery table sorter (without using jquery Data table)

This is controller class

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {

       return View(db.table_name.ToList());

 }
```

This is how I used jquery table sorter plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#table-hover")

            .tablesorter({

                widthFixed: true,
                serverSideSorting: false

            })

            .tablesorterPager({
                container: $("#pager"),
                size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val()
            });

    });
 </script>
```

Comment: You can also do this using (stored) procedure. Simply add a page number to your controller and pass it to the model and procedure. Here are some good references for pagination in SQL Server: [A More Efficient Method for Paging Through Large Result Sets](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml) and [Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using Troy Goode's **[PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList)**, also you can do this manually yourself but that would be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: this could be helpful , I'll try this

Comment: Ohh , you're awesome!!!! thanks for helping me to apply optimum solution for my matter

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using skip() and take() function should be do pagination. When you call this function pass page-no and no-of Record. And calculate records starting and display.
example you want display 2 page and 50 records then linq query like this

```
var items =contex.employee.skip(50).take(50);
```

you want display 3 page and 50 records then linq query like this

```
var items =contex.employee.skip(100).take(50);
```

Comment: actually this record count can be vary , I cannot decide how many pages are there , but definitely only 10 records per page , is that possible to it your way ?

Comment: Yes first you can run query for count and decide total page and do this.