# How to synchronize localhost database and server in java?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I am stuck at this and search a lot about it but didn't find any solution.
I created software in Netbeans that is currently connected to the local database (localhost PHPMYADMIN), now I have a server. What I want to do is that, For example, when the user clicks on the save button data must save in the local database and then upload on the server (at the backend). I didn't want to save data at the same time on both server and local because its time taking and slow down the software performance.

Comment: User in this case is only you, unless you setup phpmyadmin on each user. In that case you could have a portion of your code that does that. Ex. A class that handles saving information based on time for example, every hour. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: assume that I setup PHPMyAdmin in every user PC.

Comment: @iSpark If a class save the information and upload on the server after every one hour, then after every hour user should wait for data to upload on server.

Comment: Not necessarily, lookup worker threads.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409428/create-worker-thread-which-performs-specific-task-in-the-background