# how to records from 10 to 15 from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I get Records from 10-to15  I find some code in net Like

```
Select * 
from Employee 
LIMIT 10 to 15
```

but I am getting an error at `Limit`

Comment: What is the flavour of the database?

Comment: im writing in sql server

Comment: Look at combination of `limit` and `offset`

Comment: select * from Employee LIMIT  5 offset 10 Getting Error as Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '5'.

Comment: The correct answer is dbms specific. Please edit your question to include the relevant rdbms tag.

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: sql 2012 server

Comment: You have to make sure to include an ORDER BY, otherwise your dbms will not be consistent on which records are 10-15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offset` and `fetch next`:

```
select e.*
from Employee e
order by ??
offset 9
fetch next 6 rows only;
```

Note that `fetch` is available from SQL Server 2012 onward.

Normally, you do this with an `order by`.  The `??` is for the column/expression for ordering.  Fetching with an offset doesn't make sense without an `order by`, because result sets are in an arbitrary order unless the ordering is explicit.

In earlier (supported) versions, I would recommend `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, row_number() over (order by ??) as seqnum
      from Employee e
     ) e
where seqnum between 10 and 15;
```

Comment: Here wat is t.  Error as Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'fetch'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
Invalid usage of the option first in the FETCH statement.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use "ROW_NUMBER()". See the following code sample from this stack overflow: [Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server)

```
SELECT col1, col2 
 FROM (
 SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
 FROM MyTable
 ) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```