# Create table where each column is a distinct value retrieved from select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table where each column is a distinct value retrieved from select query.

Example:

[Query]

```
SELECT DISTINCT col 
FROM table
```

[Result]

```
col
 --- 
val1
val2
val3
val4
```

Requested table:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | ... | ColumnN
-------------------------------------------
 val1   |  val2   |  val3   | ... | valN
```

There is an unknown number of distinct values. All columns should be create as type TEXT.

Is this possible using SQL without procedures?

Thanks.

Comment: If "procedures" means dynamic sql/front end code/building an sql string and executing it etc, then the answer is No

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping for each column name of a MSSQL table using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307487/looping-for-each-column-name-of-a-mssql-table-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [dynamic command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). If you do not want to create a function, use an anonymous code block, example:

```
create table table_cols(col text);
insert into table_cols values
('col1'), 
('col2'),
('col3');

do $$
begin
    execute format('create table new_table(%s text)', string_agg(distinct col, ' text, '))
    from table_cols;
end
$$
```

Check:

```
\d new_table

            Table "public.new_table"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 col1   | text |           |          | 
 col2   | text |           |          | 
 col3   | text |           |          |
```