# Alternate of offset in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, offset

I have below stored procedure in sql server 2016, its working fine there.

Now I need to create the same sp in sql 2008, now I am getting error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetEmployees, Line 41 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] **Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'**. Msg 153, Level 15, State
>   2, Procedure GetEmployees, Line 42 [Batch Start Line 0] Invalid usage
>   of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

How to modify the same proc so that it can run over sql 2008 as well.

```
 --dbo.GetEmployees '',2,2  
    CreatePROCEDURE [dbo].GetEmployees    
    (    
     @SearchValue NVARCHAR(50) = '',    
     @PageNo INT = 0,    
     @PageSize INT = 10,    
     @SortColumn NVARCHAR(20) = 'Name',    
     @SortOrder NVARCHAR(20) = 'ASC'    
    )    
     AS BEGIN    
     SET NOCOUNT ON;    
     if @PageNo<0 set @PageNo=0   
     set @PageNo=@PageNo+1  
     SET @SearchValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchValue))    
     Set @SearchValue= nullif(@SearchValue,'')    
     ; WITH CTE_Results AS     
    (    
        SELECT EmployeeID, Name, City from tblEmployee     
     WHERE (@SearchValue IS NULL OR Name LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%')     
           ORDER BY    
      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'EmployeeID' AND @SortOrder='ASC')    
                        THEN EmployeeID    
            END ASC,    
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'EmployeeID' AND @SortOrder='DESC')    
                       THEN EmployeeID    
           END DESC,    

         CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Name' AND @SortOrder='ASC')    
                        THEN Name    
            END ASC,    
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Name' AND @SortOrder='DESC')    
                       THEN Name    
      END DESC,    

      CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'City' AND @SortOrder='ASC')    
                        THEN City    
            END ASC,    
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'City' AND @SortOrder='DESC')    
                       THEN City    
      END DESC     
          OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNo - 1) ROWS    
          FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY    
     ),    
    CTE_TotalRows AS     
    (    
     select count(EmployeeID) as MaxRows from tblEmployee WHERE (@SearchValue IS NULL OR Name LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%')    
    )    
       Select MaxRows TotalRecords, t.EmployeeID, t.Name, t.City,t.Department,t.Gender from dbo.tblEmployee as t, CTE_TotalRows     
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE_Results WHERE CTE_Results.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID)    
       OPTION (RECOMPILE)    
       END
```

Comment: `OFFSET` is not available in `SQL Server 2008`, use `row_number()` instead and calculate the row number using `@PageSize` that you have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `row_number()` window function and in the `OVER` section you want to put your entire sorting expression. Note that I've created another CTE for readability, but you could get the same thing done with just a subquery.

Formatted code for the `SELECT` statement would be the following:

```
WITH CTE_Rownums AS (
  SELECT 
    EmployeeID, 
    Name, 
    City,
    row_number() over ( ORDER BY ... ) as rn -- put your entire order by here
  FROM tblEmployee     
  WHERE 
    @SearchValue IS NULL 
    OR Name LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%'
), CTE_Results AS (    
  SELECT EmployeeID, Name, City
  FROM CTE_Rownums
  WHERE 
    (rn > @PageSize * (@PageNo - 1)
    AND (rn <= @PageSize * @PageNo)
  ORDER BY rn   
 ), CTE_TotalRows AS (    
  SELECT count(EmployeeID) as MaxRows
  FROM tblEmployee 
  WHERE 
  @SearchValue IS NULL 
  OR Name LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%'
)
SELECT MaxRows TotalRecords, t.EmployeeID, t.Name, t.City,t.Department,t.Gender
FROM dbo.tblEmployee as t
CROSS JOIN CTE_TotalRows     
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM CTE_Results
  WHERE CTE_Results.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
)    
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

In the last `SELECT` I've replaced comma separated where clause with `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: getting error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
  and Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Add `;` before `WITH`, you probably copied my solution and you don't have it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you use  2008 R2 or older you can't use `OFFSET FETCH`,

you have alternative to use `ROW_NUMBER()`   and rewrite your query for examle

with `OFFSET`

```
SELECT Price
FROM dbo.Inventory
ORDER BY Price OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

this query without `OFFSET` using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT Price
FROM
(
SELECT Price
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Price) AS Seq
FROM dbo.Inventory
)t
WHERE Seq BETWEEN 11 AND 15
```